# Hide/disable clearnet website and make only available through onion link

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, onion-routing, darknet

it seems like an easy question but I cannot find good information. I have built a PHP website that is of course available in the clearnet through the IP and I have a hidden service running (so it is available through an onion address). How do I hide my website in the clearnet and only make it reachable through its onion address through TOR?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's just as simple as putting it behind a reverse proxy: basically, Tor *is* a reverse TCP proxy for it's hidden services. So - make a *separate* localhost interface with an address like 127.0.0.**2** to make sure that no standard firewall rules will mess up, and just bind your web server to this IP and port. After that **make sure** to disable any network activity for the web server's user except that new localhost to prevent any data leaks(use a filesystem socket for database connection). That's it! Point your hidden service to 127.0.0.**2** and it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to deny clear net-based access, and only allow tor-based ones. If this is true, you must set up your machine behind an excellent firewall, that don't allow any incoming connections except for those originated from your tor-client. How to do it depends on your environment.
You can also avoid IP connections by not leaking your IP address. Only advertise your `.onion` address instead. :)